# Error Loading Jupiter Notebook and PYDEVD_DISABLE_FILE_VALIDATION=1, with frozen module off

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I was compiling the specific file and it was taking much time. So, i started to upload it on Google Colab. It did not upload and after that, this specific file does not open and gives error,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSPcd.png)

I have tried nbstripout to remove the output but still doesn't work. I tried opening it as a txt file and it gets stuck, doesn't open.